# Find lines with the least number of spaces using Unix tools

Tags: file, sorting, unix, awk, grep

I have a large file with every line in the same format (it is a *spreadsheet-like* **fixed-length** plain-text data file). I'm using *Unix* tools like `grep`, `tail`, **etc**.

I want to find lines which contain the **least number of spaces**. I take it as a crude criteria to find the most interesting lines in the file, since having less spaces means more data to check.

I imagine I could sort the lines by the number of spaces/non-space characters and get the head or tail of the output. Something like (*pseudocode*):

```
sort -by (num of spaces asc OR num of non-spaces desc) bigfile.txt
    | head -100 > interesting.txt
```

**Conversely,** I could use the same method to find lines with the **most number of spaces** as well, again to crudely check that all mandatory data is available in each line.

**Note:** Loading the whole file into memory is out of the question. So is, *grepping* for certain terms or going through the file line-by-line in `vim`. Also, details about the file content are unimportant for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with perl for example:

```
perl -ne 'print tr/ //, ":$_"' bigfile.txt
```

The `tr/ //` will count the number of spaces in the line. You could pipe this into `| sort -n | head -n 100` to find the "most interesting" lines.

You probably want to exclude blank lines:

```
perl -ne 'print tr/ //, ":$_" if length > 1' bigfile.txt
```

If you *know* that you are not interested in lines with more than `N=10` spaces then you could make the process faster by adding a check for this threshold:

```
perl -ne '$s = tr/ //; print "$s:$_" if length > 1 && $s < 10' bigfile.txt
```

This will help `sort`, as it won't need to scan the entire output. As a matter of fact, without a threshold, sorting would inevitably imply loading the entire file into memory.

Comment: Thanks for the last tip, and of course for the answer. I kinda realized that the sort takes time (loading into memory), but I managed to process a 3GB file without issues or much waiting. But I guess I could estimate a probable threshold by grabbing some random lines, even if I don't know for sure. Thanks again! Anyway, the memory comment was more for GUI tools like Notepad++ in Windows.. that's going to kill the computer even with the 12GB RAM I have!

Comment: GNU `sort` falls back to a merge sort using temporary files if it cannot fit the entire file into core. That makes it even slower, but it should cope with very large files (up to the free space on the `$TMPDIR` partition; see the man page for how to temporarily override the temp file location).

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

```
gawk -vOFS='\t' '{print length(gensub(/ /, "", "g")), $0}' bigfile.txt |
 sort -k1,1nr |
  head -100 |
   cut -f2-
```

The logic is pretty simple:

- prepend non-whitespace-chars count
- numeric-sort by count desc
- get first 100 lines
- remove prepended number

---

If you only want to print the line numbers, please use `NR` instead of `$0`, and it'll use less memory.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` to count spaces.

```
awk -F" " 'NR==1 {m=l=gsub(/ /,x);m1=l1=1;next} {s=gsub(/ /,x);if (s>m) {m=s;m1=NR};if (s<l) {l=s;l1=NR}} END {print "line="l1" has least spaces\nline="m1" has most spaces"}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print all lines with the fewest number of blank chars:

```
awk -F'[ ]' 'NR==FNR{min=(NF<min?NF:min); next} NF==min' file file
```

Is that all you were looking for? Obviously you can tweak it to print the lines with fewer than twice the min:

```
awk -F'[ ]' 'NR==FNR{min=(NF<min?NF:min); next} NF<=(2*min)' file file
```

whatever other criteria you like.